# Could not instantiate mail function

Tags: joomla1.5

i am developing a website using joomla 1.5. and i use aiContactSafe component in my "contact us" menu.i am using wamp server in my laptop.but when i try to send comment to check weather it is working it will display an error"Could not instantiate mail function." please can any one help me in solving this issue?

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to send mail from your wamp using php mail function, unless you install sendmail or something else, and configure php to use it.

Simpler solution for you is to use smtp settings in Joomla, and then it will be sent through your provider.